# View DNS server address - on mountable image.

Tags: windows-7

Running windows 7 64bit OS

I have a backup image of my C:\ with everything saved and i need to access the DNS settings ive got saved on my NIC (on the backup c:\ image), updating NIC drivers tends to revert settings back to default.

i am able to mount the image (via 3rd party software) and browse through it like a normal HDD.
is there a place/file where the NIC saves the DNS settings i can access?

Restoring my pc is out of the question as some programs will cease to work (outdated image) and preferences lost on various programs.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Kris
i followed your link and found the registry file \system which contained my DNS server settings.

i went into registry and loaded the \system hive (expanded HKLM-FILE-LOAD HIVE) and selected the file.
i browsed down to current control set went down to adapters (in sub folders) and found the adapter with the designated settings.

Thanks again!

anyone looking to load the saved file registry should follow this link
http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-offline-registry-edit.html

Comment: Happy it worked. :)